# recovery ntfs file from previuse partitions

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04, unfortunately I used the whole HDD and Ubuntu removed everything even Windows 7 from my HDD.
Can I retrieve my files?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but very unlikely. Even if you do, you will recover files, not their names or directory structures. So, thousands of files "111" "112" "113" so on. Do you need them? If yes, there is a lot of disk recovery software for Windows (just don't install Windows on that disk again)
The only exception is if you had a separate disk letter in Windows for your data and C disk was larger that the amount of files Ubuntu did write. In this case you should bring you HDD to a professional, this is not an operation that can be briefly explained. He may be able to restore your data intact.

Comment: And **stop using the system** if you really need the data. If you need to use your computer, use it with the installer USB/DVD, and do not access your HDD.